# Download and save a favicon with node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to download a favicon from a website using Node.js, but am having some trouble.

My code is as follows:

```
//Imports ...

var theurl = http.createClient(80, 'a1.twimg.com');
var requestUrl = 'http://a1.twimg.com/a/1284159889/images/favicon.ico';
var request = theurl.request('GET', requestUrl, {"host": "a1.twimg.com"});
request.end();

request.addListener('response', function (response)
{
        var body = '';
        response.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
                body += chunk;
        });
        response.addListener("end", function() {
            fs.writeFileSync('favicon.ico', body.toString('binary'), 'binary');
        });
});
```

The resulting icon is just garbage, however, and I suspect it has something to do with the encoding of the favicon when I grab it this way. What's the correct way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try as a first line in the response callback `response.setEncoding('binary')`, or (since that's not a preferred (by node) encoding to set) `response.setEncoding(null)`, which will make it a Buffer. And then just write body directly, without performing anything on it.

`fs.writeFileSync('favicon.ico', body, 'binary');`

Comment: Didn't work with response.setEncoding(null), but did work with response.setEncoding('binary').

Comment: @jimt - did you also try with `null` and then skip the third argument in the write? So that it's `fs.wFS('favicon', body);`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do `response.setEncoding("binary")` and provide the third argument to writeFileSync:

```
fs.writeFileSync('favicon.ico', body, 'binary')
```

This combination worked for me. Thanks.